# How to properly manage drawing many different shapes on google maps from a speed and data standpoint

Tags: performance, google-maps, web-applications, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous

I have an app that goes out and gets a large number of points for each zip code in a given geography. It then turns those points into a polygon roughly (since the data had to be shrunk down to send in a timely manner) representing the boundaries of a zip code and then places them on GoogleMaps. Each zip code has a popup and a color with additional info.

My question is: What is the best method of trying to keep the script from crashing on devices like iPad when the script has not hung but just needs time to process through all the data coming back to make a shape and draw it on the map?

My current thought is web workers doing part of the computation but since it still needs to come back to the main thread because it needs the window and document object there might be alternatives that I havent thought of.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do it would be to move the heavy rendering to the server-side, though that may not be practical in many cases.

If you do want to take that route, check out [Google Maps Engine](http://www.google.com.au/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html), a geo DB that can render large tables of polygons by rendering the shapes server-side and sending them to the client as map tiles.

If you're keen on keeping it client-side, then you can avoid locks on platforms like the iPad by releasing control back to the browser as much as possible.  Use `setTimeout` to run the work asynchronously and try to break it up such that you only process a single row or geometry per `setTimeout` call.